# A question on space of $l^p(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

1) give an example of $\{x_n\}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n=0 $ but 
$\{x_n\}\notin l^p(\mathbb{N}), p>1, \forall p.$

2) show that $1\le p<r$  then $l^p(\mathbb{N})\subsetneq l^r(\mathbb{N}) $

for (1) we choose $\{x_n\}=\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{p}}$ but I am not sure ..

some one can help ..thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Your example for part $(1)$ is fine since $\sum |x_n|^p = \sum \frac1n = \infty$ (as long as you are looking for one example for each value of $p$). If you want to find a single sequence that works for all values of $p$, one way to proceed is to combine a family of examples for single values of $p$. Let $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots \}$ be the prime numbers and define 
$$x_n = \begin{cases} 
      \bigg(\frac{1}{k+p_i} \bigg)^{1/p_i} & \text{ if } n = kp_i \text{ for some } i \\
       0 & \text{ otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
Then $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (I'll leave this as an exercise) and for any $p > 1$ there is a $p_i > p$. As a result, the subsequence $(x_{kp_i})$ is not in $\ell_p$, as in the first example, and hence neither is the sequence $(x_n)$.

For the second part, start by taking $(x_n) \in \ell^p$. We want to show $(x_n) \in \ell^r$. Note that since $|x_n|^p$ is summable, $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. In particular, for some $N$ and for all $n \geq N$, $|x_n| < 1$ and so $|x_n|^r < |x_n|^p$ for $n \geq N$.
Hence $$\sum |x_n|^r \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |x_n|^r + \sum_N^\infty |x_n|^p < \infty.$$

To finish, you want to find $(y_n)$ such that $\sum |y_n|^r < \infty$ but $\sum |y_n|^p = \infty$. For this, you should try to adapt your example from part $(1)$ by replacing $\frac{1}{p}$ by another suitable power of $\frac1n$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but $\frac1{n^\frac1p}$ as an example does not make sense as it will not converge for all $p>1$.

Comment: @AnthonyTer……. I think  this example not wrong

Comment: @AnthonyTer This depends on how you parse the exercise I think. I'd read it as requiring you to, for each $p$, give an example rather than give a single example that works for every $p$. With the latter reading you are of course correct.

Comment: @RhysSteele Oh ok, I can see how it can be interpreted both ways. Could you think of an example that satisfies the condition the way I read it? I couldn't.

Comment: @RhysSteele..sorry I m not understand last two steps of your proof

Comment: @AnthonyTer See my edit for an example, that works essentially by picking a family of examples for a sequence $p_i \to \infty$ and combining them into a single sequence.

Comment: @learner Could you elaborate on which bits you don't understand and what specifically you're having trouble with? It's hard to improve the answer without knowing exactly where you're stuck

Comment: @RhysSteele...you said like to finish you want to find from there I am not understand

Comment: @learner At that point all that remains is to show that $\ell^r \neq \ell^p$ so you're trying to find a sequence $y = (y_n)$ that is in $\ell^r$ but not in $\ell^p$. This final bit is a hint on how to do that (I only give a hint because you can just adapt your idea from the first part, think about which values of $a$ make $\sum \frac1{n^{aq}} < \infty$ for $q= p$ and $q=r$).

Answer (score 2):

Another example for part 1 of the exercise would be $$x_n = \frac{1}{\ln n}$$
In fact, by observing that $\frac{1/{(\ln n)^p}}{1/n} \to \infty$ and that the harmonic series diverges, you can conclude that:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^p} = \infty$$ for every $p$.